# Safe JSON conversion of objects

Tags: python, json, escaping, inject

Both `json` and `simplejson` support the extension of `json.JSONEncoder` with the purpose of serializing non-base objects. From the documentation, however, I can't understand how to do this safely.

This is my encoder:

```
class ReprEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    @staticmethod
    def of(*types):
        return ft.partial(ReprEncoder, types)

    def __init__(self, repr_types, **kwargs):
        self.__repr_types = repr_types
        super(ReprEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def default(self, obj):
        if type(obj) in self.__repr_types:
            return 'r[%r]' % obj
        return super(ReprEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

The `of` methods allows me to provide the classes for which the serialization is supported, and I represent such objects with the convention `r[%r]`. On deserialization, I plan to use a strategy like **if it matches `r[` ... `]`, then deserialize with some (possibly safe!) `eval`-like technique**

With the assumption that, for some class `C`, `C.__repr__` works [as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) I can call it as it follows:

```
c = C('foo', 'bar', 3)
json.dumps(c, cls=ReprEncoder.of(C))
```

From the documentation it's not clear how to escape strings which are accidentally matching my semantics. The idea would be: **if the string to be encoded matches the `r[`...`]` syntax, then pre-pend a backslash** + **On deserialization, look behind `r` for backslashes**.

A trick like:

```
def default(self, obj):
    # ...
    if type(obj) in types.StringTypes and obj.startswith('r'):
        obj = '\\' + obj
    return super(ReprEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Is not going to work, since the `default` method is called only when the default encoder doesn't have a clue on how to decode data. Also the `json.JSONEncode` is not implementing things like `string` (or similar) whilch I could override.

Any hint?